# Confusion with bitwise operations | and <<

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
unsigned long long n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 64; i+=2)
    n |= 1ULL << i;       //WHAT DOES THIS DO? AH!
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around what the third line of this code actually does. Someone please help clear this up!

Comment: nope, ULL means "unsigned long long"

Comment: Though does it really matter if all he's using is the bit pattern?

Comment: @tskuzzy on a 64-bit environment, yes.

Comment: It actually invokes undefined behaviour to shift a 64 bit value by 64 bits -- only 0 to 63 are allowed. Better change the `i <= 64` to `i < 64`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That line sets the i<sup>th</sup> bit of n.

- `1ULL` is the integer 1 with type unsigned long long.
- `<<` is a bitshift operator. `1ULL << i` is equal to 2<sup>i</sup>, or in binary: `100...0` with i zeros.
- `n |= x;` is a compound assignment operator. It is similar to writing `n = n | x;`.
- The operator `|` is the bitwise OR operator.

Wikipedia has an example showing how bitwise OR operator works in the general case:

```
   0101 (decimal 5)
OR 0011 (decimal 3)
 = 0111 (decimal 7)
```

**Related**

- [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)
- [Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Answer (score 1):

The `|= 1ULL << i` simply means set the `i`th bit. The for loops over every second bit so every other bit in the 64 bit unsigned long long will be set to 1.

In other words, you will get a bit pattern like `...0101010101`.

Answer (score 1):

It's left shifting 1 by i places, and OR'ing the result with n.  Effectively it's setting bit i in n.

Answer (score 1):

it binary ORs n with the value 1 bit shifted by the value of i.

I believe the (binary) value of n would be:

0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101

when the loop completed, although I haven't tested it..

Comment: I didn't see the `i+=2` so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
n |= 1ULL << i;       //WHAT DOES THIS DO? AH!
```

On the right hand side you have `"1ULL" which is a constant 1 unsigned long long`. You are `left bit shifting "1ULL" i number of times`. The result of the left shifting of "1ULL" will then be matched with n to perform a bitwise OR. So `n will be set to (n | (1ULL << i))`.

This entire line or operation is setting the ith bit of n to a 1.